# SELECT From database fast way MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I went into some problem, my database size is 48.0 MB it has `ids` column , which is contains id of a user .

**my command :**
`SELECT ids FROM users WHERE ids = $from_id AND bot_id = $botid`

**bot_id :** it's refer to where did I get this id from .

**The problem :** it's taking `1.68 sec` to give me result, it's takes a lot of time.

**i'm looking for fast way to get this result.**

**more information:**

- i use **PHP8.2 a PDO SQL** to get Query result by this command :

```PHP
$PDO->query("SELECT ids FROM `users` WHERE ids = $from_id AND bot_id = $botid");
```

- PRIMARY KEY for users table is (`id`)

EXPLAIN code :

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ids FROM users WHERE ids = 5831759304 AND bot_id = 5990762186;
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | partitions | type  | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | users | NULL       | index | idx_ids_botid | idx_ids_botid | 165     | NULL | 2057946 |     1.00 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+---------+------+---------+----------+--------------------------+
1 row in set, 4 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: What is the primary key of the `users` table?

Comment: PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

Comment: `ids` or `id` ?

Comment: ids is column contains int like this type : 128373223, (id) is the primary key for the table users.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT ids FROM users ...` and include the output in your question.

Comment: 1. Does the same query run as slow from mysql client? If so, why there is even PHP code in the question? 2. Why index length is so huge? it must be just 10, not 165. What is column type for ids and botid and what are actual values stored there?

Comment: 3. and what are numerous warnings? There must be only one. run SHOW WARNINGS after EXPLAIN

Comment: 4. Do you really have 2 million rows with ids = 5831759304?

Comment: Create index on bot_id. It might help you.

Comment: @SudiptoBhattacharya NOPE it wouldnt

Comment: 5. What is value of innodb_buffer_pool_size? if it's default 128Mb, then you need to increase it, consider using value of 50% of ram available on the server.

Comment: `key_len` of 165 for `idx_ids_botid` index is way too big for 2 int fields. Are these fields integers? Could you please provide the CREATE TABLE statement for `users`, give a couple of rows as example and say what is the size of the table (how many rows it has)?

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE users;` and post the result into your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with some basics:

**Add Indexes**: Speed up your query by adding an index on `ids` and `bot_id`.

```sql
ALTER TABLE users ADD INDEX idx_ids_botid (ids, bot_id);
```

**Use Prepared Statements**: Your code is open to SQL injection. Use PDO prepared statements to secure it:

```php
$stmt = $PDO->prepare("SELECT ids FROM users WHERE ids = :from_id AND bot_id = :botid");
$stmt->bindParam(':from_id', $from_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':botid', $botid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
```

**Server Optimization**: Check your MySQL server settings. Adjust buffer sizes if needed.

**Hardware**: If possible, use SSDs over HDDs for faster access.

**Analyze Query**: Use `EXPLAIN` before your query to see how it's processed.

**Caching**: For frequent queries, consider caching tools like Redis.

**Maintain Database**: Occasionally run `OPTIMIZE TABLE` to maintain your database.

#### Adjusting Buffer Size

1. **Edit MySQL Config**: Open with:

```bash
sudo nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

or

```bash
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
```

2. **Set Buffer Size**: Under `[mysqld]`, add or modify:

```ini
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 6G
```

(Use 70-80% of your server's RAM.)

3. **Restart MySQL**:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

4. **Monitor**: Check query performance and adjust if needed.

That's it! Adjusting this setting can help speed up MySQL, but keep an eye on overall system performance.

Comment: i'm now using this command :
`SELECT ids FROM `users` USE INDEX (idx_ids_botid) WHERE ids = 5831759304 AND bot_id = 5990762186;`

but still same problem . could you teach me how to adjust the buffer size . 

os : ubuntu 20.0.4

Comment: MySQL may already be using the index on `id`.

Comment: Using an SSD over HDD shouldn't help much for this query, given indices are set and the buffers adjusted

Comment: thank you so much it's works, after editing innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G it now way more faster , i'm now able to grab data within 0.005 sec.

Comment: could you tell me the damages may causing if i set innodb_buffer_pool_size = 20G ?

Comment: Yeah, system instability and crashes. MySQL would be effectively consuming a large amount of RAM memory hence the formula: `Math.min(0.8 * totalRAM, 'Size of your InnoDB data and indexes in GB');`